# CakePHP project not working when upload to live?

Tags: php, cakephp, multiple-projects

Now I'm working in cakePHP project, It was working in localhost, But when I uploaded to live, It was getting 500 Internal Server error. Could you please advice me what is the problem is this and How to solve this?
FYI : My server contains more than 6 cakePHP projects.

Please advice me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check the server/php error log, there's likely an error message in there somewhere.

Comment: And set debug to 2 for a while to debug this. Sounds like you got some experience already. Running five other cake apps you really should be able to tell us more about the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 Internal server error is an webserver (Apache) error, not a CakePHP error. Most likely it has to do with the .htaccess file that is needed to get the 'pretty URLs' for Cake working.

Comment: okay, you are right, But all other cakephp projects were working fine in the same pattern, How to determine the .htaccess file.

Comment: Check for typos, and new/others options that you have used in your .htaccess file. Apache gives a 500 error too if you are using a module or option that is not allowed (check the logs). *Something* must be different....

Answer (score 0):

Trust me, we all had the same problems. Now, I can tell only from my experience:

1. Check for **mod_rewrite** on your server.
2. If you wrote the code with Notepad++ make sure you converted it to "**UTF-8 without BOM**" with "**Encode => Convert to UTF-8 without BOM**" in your Notepad++. This was an epic mistake for me because I've spend 3 days on this one.
3. Make sure you don't have any preceding characters before `<?php` in your files (try with Vim).
4. Make sure that the **tmp** folder is writable `chmod -R 775 tmp/` in shell.

If I get any new ideas, I'll edit this answer. Good luck! I know how it feels. ^^

Comment: Yes, Now I'm working in Notepad++ only and possiblities are there like you said, But I dont think so this is the problem.  Coz Now I have uploaded fresh cakephp file into server and I got same error like before, Afterthat I have changed my .htaccess, Now its working fine. I will post my code down...